# How do I bind a property in view element to view-model property without using dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, element

I have a WPF MVVM project which has a property of type `OudPattern`.
I would like to bind this property to `OudPatternEditor1` which is a `UserControl` in view. is there any way to do this using `INotifyPropertyChange`. Since I'm already using it in my project.

Please notice that `OudPatternEditor1` is instantiated at the startup using a `new OudPattern()`. But this pattern can be changed by user. so I need to update this property in the view model and `OudEditor1` also.

I solved the problem by passed the view to the view model and updating this property in there each time. But I know that this approach is against the MVVM principles of decoupling view and view model.

I also tried to solve this using dependency property but i failed to get a solution.

**Custom user control XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyOudTeacher.OudMachine.OudPatternEditor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Visibility="Visible">

    <Canvas x:Name="oudGridCanvas"/>
</UserControl>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class OudPatternEditor : UserControl
{
    private OudPattern oudPattern;
    private double gridSquareWidth = 15;// my code: default 20
    private double namesColumnWidth = 50;//my code: default 100

    public OudPatternEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.oudPattern = new OudPattern();
        DrawNoteNames();
        DrawPattern(namesColumnWidth);
        DrawGridLines(namesColumnWidth);
    }

    public OudPattern OudPattern
    {
        get { return oudPattern; }
        set {
            oudPattern = value;
            UpdateHitView();
        }
    }

/* more code... */
}
```

**The view XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyOudTeacher.OudMachine.OudMachineView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyOudTeacher.OudMachine">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="262*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <my:OudPatternEditor Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20" x:Name="oudPatternEditor1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Command="{Binding StopCommand}" Margin="2" ToolTip="Stop">
                <Rectangle Fill="DarkBlue" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="3" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
            </Button>
<!-- more code... -->
```

**view model**

```
class OudMachineViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDisposable
{
    private IWavePlayer waveOut;
    private OudPattern pattern;
    private OudPatternEditor OudPatternEditor;
    private OudPatternSampleProvider patternSequencer;
    private int tempo;
    private string selectedFile;

    public ICommand PlayCommand { get; }
    public ICommand StopCommand { get; }
    public ICommand UpdateXmlCommand { get; }
    public ICommand OpenFileCommand { get; }
    public ICommand PauseCommand { get; }

    public OudMachineViewModel(OudPatternEditor oudPatternEditor)
    {
        this.OudPattern = oudPatternEditor.OudPattern;
        this.OudPatternEditor = oudPatternEditor;
        Tempo = OudPattern.ScoreHits.ScaledTempo;
        PlayCommand = new DelegateCommand(Play);
        StopCommand = new DelegateCommand(Stop);
        OpenFileCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenFile);
        PauseCommand = new DelegateCommand(Pause);
    }

    public OudPattern OudPattern
    {
        get { return pattern; }
        set
        {
            pattern = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OudPattern");
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSelectedFile()
    {
        OudPattern = new OudPattern(selectedFile);
        OudPatternEditor.OudPattern = this.OudPattern;
        Tempo = OudPattern.ScoreHits.ScaledTempo;
    }

/* more code... */
```

The correct way is NOT to pass `OudEditor` to the view model constructor. since this is against MVVM. I expect to find a way to update `OudEditor1.OudPattern` by binding it to `ViewModel.OudPattern`

Edit #1:

I was able to add a dependency property and achieve what I wanted. The code added is simple:

**view code-behind:**

```
public OudPattern OudPattern
{
    get { return (OudPattern)GetValue(OudPatternProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(OudPatternProperty, value);
        DrawNewPattern();
        UpdateHitView();
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty OudPatternProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("OudPattern", typeof(OudPattern), typeof(OudPatternEditor), 
        new PropertyMetadata(default(OudPattern)));
```

**view XAML above, modified:**

```
<my:OudPatternEditor Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20" x:Name="oudPatternEditor1" VerticalAlignment="Top" OudPattern="{Binding OudPattern}"/>
```

**view model:**

```
public OudPattern OudPattern
{
    get { return pattern; }
    set
    {
        pattern = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("OudPattern");
    }
}
```

But I noticed that the setter for the dependency property in my view code-behind never executes. I learned that those setters are not executed when called from outside. How do I make the view code-behind react to external change and do the methods mentioned in the setter above? i.e.

```
DrawNewPattern();
UpdateHitView();
```

Edit# 2:
I found an answer to my last question about dependency property setter. Thanks for Elgonzo to point out that I can use property changed callbacks.

The code should be modified to add OnPatternChanged callback

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OudPatternProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OudPattern", typeof(OudPattern), typeof(OudPatternEditor), 
            new PropertyMetadata(default(OudPattern),OnPatternChanged));

    private static void OnPatternChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myObject = (OudPatternEditor)d;
        myObject.DrawNewPattern();
        myObject.UpdateHitView();
```

Note that you cant call none static methods directly from static OnPatternChanged.. so you need to cast the sender into object and call its member methos.

Comment: Having a OudPatternEditor instance, i.e. a UserControl in a view model is against MVVM. View models do know nothing about the view, especially do they not hold references to view elements.

Comment: As you didn't succeed using DependencyProperties, why don't you ask about that? Its the cleanest MVVM approach available in WPF.

Comment: In WPF, the target of a binding has to be a DependencyProperty. Period. End of discussion ;-) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview (There are ugly hacks using some forms of binding proxies/detours to "workaround" this requirement without actually violating this requirement, but you do so at your own peril: http://blog.lexique-du-net.com/index.php?post/2010/03/31/Binding-on-a-Property-which-is-not-a-DependencyProperty)

Comment: @ Clemens, thank you for Highlighting that. I actually mentioned that at the end of my post. I is against MVVM but i used it just to get around my problem temporarily. That is why I am asking now for a better way to do this.

Comment: @LuckyLikey Thanks for replying. I didn't want to exclude the possibility of having good help from you guys about another way to do binding. That is why i didn't ask for a particular way of solving this. I am also a little confused about Binding in WPF, that is why i will benefit from all replies and different techniques to solve this.

Comment: @elgonzo.. so why do i have to define a dependency Property for some properties while i just do simple Binding for other properties? .. in my code i simply Bound some ICommnads and other properties without the need for dependency Props.

Comment: I said the **`target`** has to be a DependencyProperty. The first link in my previous comments explains the basics of bindings, including what is a target and what is a source in a binding (i guess you confuse binding source with binding target...)

Comment: @elgonzo Thanks for the links.. very helpful.. i will update you with what i did to implement dependency property.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.. i wonder if there is a way to make the setter of dependency property do some work.. i m not able to do this in the code above.. any ideas ?

Comment: DP's don't have setters like normal properties. Don't confuse this with the CLR property facade implemented alongside a DP, whose purpose is just so you could get and set the value of a DP in code-behind as if it were "_just an ordinary property_". Instead of property setters, a DP can employ a so-called `PropertyChangedCallback`. Google for something like "DependencyProperty PropertyChangedCallback" and you should find plenty of reading material about this topic (even if you were googling for something like "DependencyProperty setter", you should quickly come across PropertyChangedCallback)

Comment: @elgonzo Thanks again for another helpful advice.. i was able to use property changed callbacks to call some methods upon dependency property change.. i will put this edit above.. thx again

Comment: @أحمدأبوعمر, don't put it into the question. Questions here on StackOverflow are supposed to be questions, not a scratchpad/notepad for recording information related to your coding endeavours ;-)

Comment: I am not trying to make a scratch pad here my friend.. I found an answer for each question I asked and i see i have to answer each one so any one have the same question will find the answers.. my Questions were: 1- how to bind property from view to view model 2- how to do than with dependency property. 3- why is the setters of dependency properties won't do the logic inside them... I answered those three question when i found the answer.. Thanks